# Does it become true whatever you think during Azan?

Tags: dua

I know Azan is the best time to ask for a Dua. But whatever you think during does it become real? I mean you are not making a Dua it's just an imagination.

Comment: Any claim that has a basis in Islam should have an evidence, what is the evidence you've been told?

Answer (score 0):

Salamalaikum Fikd,

This belief has no basis in Islam and hence cannot be considered as true. Definitely when Allah wills things happen however, Allah has clearly mentioned throughout the Quran his sunnat (practice) when it comes to accepting dua etc.

Allah says in Quran in 2:186

> And if My servants ask you about Me, I am near answering the calls of
> those who call to Me. So let them respond to Me and believe in Me that
> they may be guided.

So, Firstly this has not much to do with Azan.
Secondly, the act of dua is the belief that Allah can make happen what you wish for and so you ask him for it.

Thinking of something during Azan is not dua nor is about asking Allah for something. So this belief has no basis in Quran or Islam

Comment: In Islam we have blessed times. Azhan as is one of them. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Islam values times and places. Like night of Qadr or holy Masjid al-Haram and other places.

Similarly the time of Azhan, rain, sickness, when we sit down for food, etc are all times that are blessed. If a time is blessed then there's more chance for our dua to come tru. Having that said Allah doesn't grant all wishes. It's just higher chance. The only thing that Allah does promise is his attention to us. That's what matters the most. Right?

You're late for a plane. You ask Allah to make you get there on time. Simply by asking Allah to help you, he will give you tranquility (سکینه) yet you may still end up not getting to the plane.

If my child comes and says "Daddy Daddy ...let's go to the park" And I don't even look at her, then she's going to feel really down. But if I look at her. Show her love with my eyes, but then say "honey I can't do it right now" then I've given her that peace of mind, that tranquility. When we seek Allah's help, Allah makes our hearts firm — regardless of the outcome...